# Alternatives to using switch-case for selecting an element on a page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

I'm using selenium to automate interaction with a table on a webpage.

The table has a few columns and I'm sorting the data in the table by clicking on the sortable-headers (column names)

I've used a switch-case statement such as

```
switch(columnName){

case: "firstname": 

     columnHeader=driver.findElement(By.xpath());

case: "lastname":

     columnHeader=driver.findElement(By.xpath());

...
...

 and so on.

}
```

What could be a better alternative to using switch-case. 
Also I used this since I didn't want to write a separate method for each column.

Comment: You can easily find the element directly with proper selector. Why do you even need to use switch case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to go ahead and write a method to sort the table for each column. This prevents a few problems... 1) consumers don't have to look at the page to remember what all columns are available to sort by, 2) consumers don't have to look at the code for the function you are writing to understand what string they need to pass to sort by the desired column, 3) you don't have to worry about handing bad strings, 4) consumers don't have to worry about passing a bad string, and so on. Many of these problems won't be caught at compile time which means you will (or may) find them when the script is running. You want to give preference to finding as many bugs as possible at compile time. It will save you a LOT of time and prevent a LOT of bugs down the road.

Other benefits are that consumers look at the API and see methods like `.sortTableByFirstName()`, `.sortTableByLastName()`, etc. and it's obvious what each function does and it moves bugs into compile time because you can't call some method that doesn't exist because the name was typo'd.